# How do i start an xterm and follow by setenv in the new xterm?

Tags: perl, xterm, setenv

I am writing a perl script, and the objective is to kick start an xterm, follow by setenv, follow by invoke a tool that pre-installed in the system.

Here is my system call command in my perl script

```
system("xterm","-hold", "-e", "setenv ZI_LIBERTY_IGNORE_CONSTRUCT_FILES $RAW_RF_DIR/lib/lib2v/qcdc_ignore", "setenv HOME_0IN /p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux26/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4g_5/linux_x86_64", "modpath -n 1 \$HOME_0IN/bin", "modpath -n 1 \$HOME_0IN/modeltech/bin", "/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux30/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4f_5/linux_x86_64/bin/qcdc -c -licq -do run.tcl");
```

xterm was able to start, however it stopped when executing the setenv, after that i tried with the new command by replacing the setenv with $ENV

```
system("xterm","-hold", "-e", "\$ENV{ZI_LIBERTY_IGNORE_CONSTRUCT_FILES} = \"$RAW_RF_DIR/lib/lib2v/qcdc_ignore\"", "setenv HOME_0IN /p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux26/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4g_5/linux_x86_64", "modpath -n 1 \$HOME_0IN/bin", "modpath -n 1 \$HOME_0IN/modeltech/bin", "/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux30/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4f_5/linux_x86_64/bin/qcdc -c -licq -do run.tcl");
```

Here is the error message showing up in the new xterm (same for both approach)

```
Can't execvp $ENV{ZI_LIBERTY_IGNORE_CONSTRUCT_FILES} = "/nfs/fm/stod/stod4003/w.eew.100/rf_uprev_model_2020ww14p1//subIP/hip/MTLM_SA/RF.1//lib/lib2v/qcdc_ignore": No such file or directory
```

Please advise that how to make the series of operation works in the new xterm? Thanks!

-Eric-

Answer (score 2):

The program run with `-e` must be a program, not a shell built-in like `setenv`. Off the top of my head, I can think of two solutions:

1. Set the environment variables *before* starting xterm. They would then be inherited by xterm.
2. Let the program run by xterm be a shell, and use that shell to set the environment variables and launch the tool. Something like this (untested):

   system("xterm", "-e", "/bin/sh", "-c", "FOO=bar; FIE=fum; /run/my/program");

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Instead of doing the system call of `xterm`, in my current situation i need to use another method launch the xterm in order to pass all the required setup to the newly launched xterm. It is `simbuild` command look like this, `simbuild -dut usbx -1c -CUST MTLM_SA -1c- -ace "xterm"`, may I know how to use it in the system call?

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page I read, the following is the syntax of the `-e` option:

```
-e program [ arguments ... ]
```

It takes a path to a program, and optionally arguments to pass to that program. Specifically, it doesn't take a shell command. (It would be bad to accept a shell command without having the user specify for which shell!) That doesn't preclude one from running a shell command, though. This simply requires launching a shell, as the following does:

```sh
xterm -e sh -c shell_cmd
```

Solution:

```
my $script = <<'__EOS__';
export ZI_LIBERTY_IGNORE_CONSTRUCT_FILES="$RAW_RF_DIR/lib/lib2v/qcdc_ignore"
export HOME_0IN=/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux26/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4g_5/linux_x86_64
modpath -n 1 "$HOME_0IN/bin"
modpath -n 1 "$HOME_0IN/modeltech/bin"
/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux30/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4f_5/linux_x86_64/bin/qcdc -c -licq -do run.tcl
__EOS__

system("xterm", "-hold", "-e", "sh", "-c", $script)
```

Since a process normally passes a copy of its env vars to process it creates, you could also write the above as follows:

```
local $ENV{ZI_LIBERTY_IGNORE_CONSTRUCT_FILES} = "$ENV{RAW_RF_DIR}/lib/lib2v/qcdc_ignore";
local $ENV{HOME_0IN} = "/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux26/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4g_5/linux_x86_64";

my $script = <<'__EOS__';
modpath -n 1 "$HOME_0IN/bin"
modpath -n 1 "$HOME_0IN/modeltech/bin"
/p/hdk/rtl/cad/x86-64_linux30/mentor/questaCDC/V10.4f_5/linux_x86_64/bin/qcdc -c -licq -do run.tcl
__EOS__

system("xterm", "-hold", "-e", "sh", "-c", $script)
```

You can use `csh` similarly; I'm simply more familiar with `sh`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution. I tested the method and it works. However, the xterm is started is fresh and there is no setup at all. In my current environment, i usually use a in-house command to start xterm, by doing that the newly launched xterm will contain all the required setup. Here is the command
simbuild -dut usbx -1c -CUST MTLM_SA -1c- -ace "xterm"
How do I put it in the first field of system call? I tried it but not successful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `simbuild`. Are you saying you want to use it to launch `xterm?` If so, does it take a program and arguments like `xterm -e`? Does it take a shell command? If so, for which shell?

Comment: Yes, i want to use `simbuild` command to launch xterm, with passing in several switches such as `-dut` etc. In fact I am not sure if it take shell command, but one thing i can confirm is that after successfully launched the xterm using simbuild command, the xterm is in tcsh.